# How to pass my JWT to external API via Axios interceptor without having to call getSession?

Tags: next.js, axios, jwt, next-auth

I've got an app using NextAuth and the AzureADB2CProvider, it's all working great, but I'm seeing something that I'm sure can't be right.

Currently, I'm passing the auth token I received from the provider in all requests to an external API via an Axios interceptor, which works fine:

```
import { AxiosRequestHeaders, InternalAxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { AccessToken } from './types';

export const UserToken = async (config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
  const session = await getSession();

  if (!session) return config;

  const token = session.accessToken as AccessToken;

  config.headers = {
    ...config.headers,
    ...(!!token && { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` })
  } as AxiosRequestHeaders;

  return config;
};
```

However, I'm seeing a behaviour where the call to `getSession` is prompting a call `/api/session` before every API request. This is not ideal and I'm *sure* the result of me doing something wrong!

Since I'm doing this within an Axios interceptor, I'm not able to try the `useSession` hook, though I'm guessing that might result in the same behaviour. I'm hoping there may be some ability of NextAuth to make the auth token available outside of React components without having to make a call to `/api/session` in order to get it.

It really feels like I'm missing something fundamental here, is anyone able to shed any light please?